# About graphics.h, winbgim.h and libbgi.a libraries in codeblock

Tags: codeblocks, bgi, winbgi

I added the full library graphic.h, winbgim.h, libbgi.a and its path in **linker setting** and **other linker** but it didn't work and it showed an error:

```
ld.exe cannot find -lbgi
```

Answer (score 1):

`ld` will give you that error if it can't find `libbgi.a` for static builds or `libbgi.dll.a` shared builds.

Make sure the path containing `libbgi.a` is set it the linker paths as in this screenshot:
[image]

Another thing you could try is to build a static version of your project in order to avoid using a missing shared library.

Comment: Can you list the exact contents of the that folder you put in there? And what exactly is the error message? Are you sure the library file you are trying to uses matches your architecture (you're not mixing win32 and win64)?

Comment: graphic.h and winbgim.h: I put in **C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include**.     The exact error message is: > ld.exe    cannot find -lbgi                      I  use **win64**

Comment: Just dropping stuff into the MinGW folder is not the best idea.
Better is to put this in a folder containing 3rd party libraries and adding the `include` folder to the compiler search directories and the `lib` folder to the linker search directories in your Code::Blocks project or even in the Code::Blocks compiler settings.